# Magento 1.9 - alternative to <afterText> in local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, link, tags

I have the fallowing code in my module local.xml:

```
  <reference name="top.links">
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="mymodule" >
         <label>Messages</label>
         <url>mymodule/account/list/</url>
         <title>Messages</title>
         <prepare>true</prepare>
         <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl" />
         <position>30</position>
         <liParams><![CDATA[ class="title_li"]]></liParams>
         <aParams><![CDATA[ class="title_a"]]></aParams>              <beforeText></beforeText>
         <afterText helper="module/returnValue"></afterText>
     </action>
  </reference>
```

As you can see in the **afterText** tag, it calls the returnValue function from my module helper and I display the value returned in front of my top.link. I would like to know if there is someway to display something like that in the **label** tag to be part of the same link or something like that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try `<label helper="module/returnValue"></label>` ?

Comment: Omg, I fell so stupid right now...thanks for the tip, it worked.
Besides that, the function is returning the result: "Messages (+".$var")", that shows something like "Messages +3". There is anyway to add like a css only in the number? Make it green perhaps.

Comment: I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy peasy solution:

```
<label helper="module/returnValue"></label>
```

Comment: Besides that, the function is returning the result: "Messages (+".$var")", that shows something like "Messages +3". There is anyway to add like a css only in the number? Make it green perhaps.